# Call onChange method in AJAX call

Tags: javascript, struts2

I have one dropdown list, and making another drop down list with the selected value from first drop down list.

```
<s:select name="selectedList" list="list" listKey="name" listValue="name"
      onchange="showList(this);return false;"/>

     <s:url id="server_url" action="cls/ListAction"/> 
     <sx:div showLoadingText="false" id="details" href="ListAction" theme="ajax"
         listenTopics="show_server_list" formId="config_frm"><sx:div>
```

And reult ajax jsp:

```
<s:select name="selectedApplication" 
          list="applications" listKey="name" 
          listValue="name" onchange="javascript:hideFilterSection();"/>
```

Here I have onchange method hideFilterSection, this is not calling...

So I have two dropdowns, first and second(ajax) , and based on the second dropdown value I need hide something in the jsp, but second dropdown onchange is not calling , please let me know how I can achieve it

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to avoid using the old, buggy built-in Dojo version, and to migrate to Struts2-jQuery plugin or even better to raw jQuery.

But coming to your question, you are missing the `executeScripts` parameters, that is `false` by default.

From [the documentation](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/dojo-div.html):

> **executeScripts**: Javascript code in the fetched content will be executed

This should work:

```
<sx:div executeScripts = "true"
       showLoadingText = "false" 
                    id = "details" 
                  href = "ListAction" 
                 theme = "ajax"
          listenTopics = "show_server_list" 
                formId = "config_frm" >
</sx:div>
```

Note that you need to set `separateScripts` to `false` (default is `true`), to access a javascript function defined in the main JSP from the result JSP, otherwise you would need to define the `hideFilterSection()` function inside the result JSP, because their scope would be separated.

> **separateScripts**: Run scripts in a separate scope, unique for each tag

Comment: Thanks Ligios for your time and reply.

I have tried what you suggested, but still its not calling the js method :( and in our project we are not using struts2-Jquery

        <sx:div executeScripts="true" showLoadingText="false"           id="details" href="serverListAction" theme="ajax"
            listenTopics="show_server_list" formId="config_frm"></sx:div>

Comment: Hi, the solution you suggested is not working...
the js method in the result jsp is not calling 
            <s:select name="selectedApplication" list="applications" listKey="name" listValue="name" onchange="javascript:hideFilterSection();"/>

Comment: i have tried that option, still its not calling the js method.
And i have also tired that setting to the s:select tag          
I am seeing the js method is loaded. (seen in the fire bug) but its not getting called via onChange :(

Comment: Tried by setting both the tags in main jsp and ajax jsp , still not working .<sx:div separateScripts="false" executeScripts="true" howLoadingText="false" id="details" href="serverListAction" theme="ajax" listenTopics="show_server_list" formId="config_frm"></sx:div> <s:select  executeScripts="true" separateScripts="false" name="selectedApplication" list="applications" listKey="name" listValue="name" onchange="hideFilterSection();"/>

Comment: Do you click on the select to trigger the onchange method ? :o)

Comment: Yes of course :)
Here we have two drop downs, second drop down(which has onChange method) will get changed based on selection of frist drop down.
Its weired for me, why its not getting called

Comment: You have Select ONE; onchange of it, you load Select TWO inside the sx:div. Then, *when you manually change* Select TWO, a javascript function must be invoked. Your problem is that your javascript function (triggered by Select TWO) is not invoked, and you have no errors in javascript console. This makes no sense... is all right ? Check every word please.

Comment: Thanks...I understood. Problem i have only one value in the second drop down, so its not getting called ..i added two values to the second drop down and tried. JS method is getting. Sorry for confusing you..
Actually i need to call the js method as soon as the second drop down has value. If it has one value, onChange is not working. any suggestion on this please?

Comment: I told you it didn't make sense :D BTW, put this at the end of result JSP: <script>hideFilterSection();</script>, and remember to accept the answer...

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the sx: tags are not working in IE 10 or 11. If you still want to use it in IE 10+ then you need to have `meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"` in the header and it must be the first meta tag in the header. It will tell IE to use IE 9 compatible mode.

Secondly, make sure your js files which contains or relate to `hideFilterSection()` is in your query page not the ajax result page.

Last but not least, I can't find any error above. Plz check your js function and its reference or the IE version you use.